# Transfer epic to another project

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

we are currently using VSTS to store all our projects.

At the start, we decided to put every work into the same project, and split them using area when creating epics, pbis etc. For multiple reasons, we have decided to split our work into different project that now represent clients.

Moving the cards is quite painful, because the option given only moves the card to a given sprint, and do not move the parent cards or the child card. For exemple: I'm moving the *PBI1* from the project *ACME* to the project *EMCA*, both have the same number of sprint, *EMCA* is a duplicate of *ACME* in that sense. The problem is when moving *PBI1* in *ECMA*, all the child tasks stayed in *ACME*.

Is there a better way to transfer all my work to the new project?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to connect VSTS to Excel to make the transfer.

[Marketplace Add-in VSTS Open in Excel](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=blueprint.vsts-open-work-items-in-excel)

Once you have done that, you can **Save** your original Project's Epics, Stories, etc. in Excel format.
Then open your other Project and **Insert** your Epics, Stories, etc. from that Excel document.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [VSTS Sync Migration Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=nkdagility.vsts-sync-migration#), this tool support bulk migration of work items  with the links:

> **LinkMigrationContext** - Migrates all the work item links, both
>   between work items and external links.

There are two ways to use these tools:

- Install from [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/packages/vsts-sync-migrator/)
- Download the [latest release from GitHub](https://github.com/nkdAgility/vsts-sync-migration/releases) and unzip.

Find [here](https://vsts-bulk-editor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) the documentation and how to migrate the work items with the links.